# How to get certificates from remote computer using c#?

Tags: c#, windows, certificate, ssl-certificate

I want to add a certificate in XML for signing purpose and  the certificate is installed on  a remote machine.
How can i access that certificate ?

Comment: you can't access certificate's private key from remote computer. You should perform signing process on that remote computer.

Comment: That's fine. I have resolved by publishing website on the remote server and accessed local certificates.